# use one countdown script for multiple countdowns

Tags: javascript, forms, countdown

I want to use a countdown script like this

```
     var montharray=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")

function countdown(yr,m,d,idCountdown){
    var theyear=yr;
    var themonth=m;
    var theday=d;
    var today=new Date();
    var todayy=today.getYear();
    if (todayy < 1000)
        todayy+=1900
    var todaym=today.getMonth();
    var todayd=today.getDate();
    var todayh=today.getHours();
    var todaymin=today.getMinutes();
    var todaysec=today.getSeconds();
    var todaystring=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy+" "+todayh+":"+todaymin+":"+todaysec;
    var futurestring=montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr;
    var dd=Date.parse(futurestring)-Date.parse(todaystring);
    var dday=Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
    var dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
    var dmin=Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
    var dsec=Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);
    var dag = "dagen";

    if(dday==0&&dhour==0&&dmin==0&&dsec==1){
        document.getElementById(idCountdown).value=current;
        return;
    }
    else if(dday<=1) {
        dag = 'dag';
    }
    document.getElementById(idCountdown).value=dday+ ' ' + dag + ' ' +dhour+" uur "+dmin+" min "+dsec+" sec";
    setTimeout(function(){countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,idCountdown);}, 1000);
}
```

in my html page i will have a textfield like this

```
 <input name="aktie1" type="text" class="countdownTekst" size="27" readonly="readonly">
 <input name="aktie2" type="text" class="countdownTekst" size="27" readonly="readonly">
```

Then i use this to use the function

```
countdown(2012,7,30, 'aktie1')
```

The last one is the ID for the textfield. But when i do it like this i will get an error

```
 document.forms.count.idCountdown.value is undefined
```

How do i get the id for that textfield in that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the input like this: `document.forms.count[idCountdown].value`

EDIT: This fiddle is working http://jsfiddle.net/Fy2FM/4/ . The bigger problem is that you are not declaring the variables with `var yourvar`, and this makes the variables to be part of the global object. Because of this, you were always seeing the same in both countdowns, because in fact you were accessing the same variables.

Comment: thanks. When i do this the formfields load with the days etc but it is not counting down anymore and i get this error in FB: TypeError: document.forms.count[idCountdown] is undefined

Comment: @RickWeller Maybe the problem is here: `setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday)", 1000)`. Try this:
`setTimeout(function(){countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,idCountdown);}, 1000);`

Comment: that seems to be the problem. Only when i do this it will load all the countdowns but when it starts to count it will only use the aktie2 date :(

Comment: @RickWeller can you use jsfiddle to show all the code? It will be better to try to find out what the problem is. Just to be sure, you want that both input elements countdown, don't you?

Comment: The fiddle is working for me. It also works with document.forms.count[idCountdown].value if you don't change de `name` attribute by an `id` attribute.

Comment: strange i see in both fields the same time counting

Answer (score 0):

where add specific time in this script for example: *3:44*

```
<script language="javascript">countdown(2016,6,20,15:44 'aktie1')</script>
```